# pylint does not catch obvious error

Tags: python, pylint

This is my code:

```
class Horse:

    def talk(self):
        print 'Hihaaa!'


class Farm:

    def __init__(self, animal):
        self.animal = animal

    def animaltalk(self):
        self.animal.sing()


def main():
    horse = Horse()
    farm = Farm(horse)
    farm.animaltalk()


main()
```

This is my `pylint`:

```
$ pylint --version
No config file found, using default configuration
pylint 1.4.3, 
astroid 1.3.6, common 0.63.2
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
```

This is the output of pylint:

```
$ pylint farm.py

************* Module farm
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  1, 0: Missing class docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  1, 0: Old-style class defined. (old-style-class)
W:  1, 0: Class has no __init__ method (no-init)
C:  3, 4: Missing method docstring (missing-docstring)
R:  3, 4: Method could be a function (no-self-use)
R:  1, 0: Too few public methods (1/2) (too-few-public-methods)
C:  7, 0: Missing class docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  7, 0: Old-style class defined. (old-style-class)
C: 12, 4: Missing method docstring (missing-docstring)
R:  7, 0: Too few public methods (1/2) (too-few-public-methods)
C: 16, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
```

I am not interested in all those warnings/messages, unless they really have to do with my problem, which is: `pylint` is unable to tell me that `self.animal.sing()` is an **error** (it should be `self.animal.talk()`).

- Is there a way of forcing `pylint` to perform a deeper analysis, or is this a fundamental limitation of the Python language?
- Or is there a better pattern to code this kind of functionality (an object collecting other pre-instantiated objects), so that `pylint` can perform better error-checking?

The reason why I need this is that, in complex code, big refactorings cause errors that are not caught by `pylint`, which means that the only way to catch them is with testing; unfortunately, I have no tests for all my code paths. A better `pylint` analysis would go a long way towards solving obvious problems in my code.

Comment: I haven't found a "linter" for python that satisfies me. Try mypy, it's buggy in some cases but quite useful: http://mypy-lang.org/

Note that the pypi package `mypy` is unrelaged, you want `pip3 install --user mypy-lang`

Comment: That's not what `pylint` is for. Python is a dynamic language, and a static analysis cannot tell you whether `Horse.sing` is patched at runtime, or handled by `__getattr__`/`__getattribute__`, or ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe: well, pylint will very readily complain with `Instance of 'Farm' has no 'animaltalk2' member` if you are making the mistake of doing `farm.animaltalk2()`, and `Farm` could **also** be patched at runtime.

Comment: That's true, but it only goes so deep; `animal` isn't *required* to be a `Horse`!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: OK, so it is not the patching, it is the fact that `pylint` does not know what the `animal` init parameter is. Is there any way of telling `pylint` about it?

Comment: There are various options for type hinting (e.g. annotations in 3.x) but I don't think they'd catch this. You're going to need to add those tests!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please report it to pylint's bug tracker: https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/. That's actually a problem because in pylint, Instances don't know their arguments. This should be easily fixable.

Comment: Done: https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issue/553/pylint-does-not-catch-obvious-error

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of forcing `pylint` to perform a deeper analysis

No.

> or is this a fundamental limitation of the Python language?

Well, it’s theoretically possible to keep writing smarter and smarter analyzers. You could certainly write a Pylint plugin that would catch your particular error (but fail in other similar cases). There is [PySonar2](https://github.com/yinwang0/pysonar2) which may or may not cover your case.

> Or is there a better pattern to code this kind of functionality (an object collecting other pre-instantiated objects), so that `pylint` can perform better error-checking?

Good question. I find that there is often a way to tweak the code to make Pylint more useful on it. In your case, however, the best I can think of is using special subclasses of `Farm`, such as `SingingFarm` or `HorseFarm`, like this:

```
class Farm:

    def __init__(self, animal):
        self.animal = animal


class SingingFarm(Farm):

    def animalsing(self):
        self.animal.sing()
```

Then Pylint will complain if you call `animalsing` on a wrong type of `Farm`. Of course, this is a very limited approach that may not work for you.

Still, I believe `grep` is the only tool that can give you any sort of assurance when refactoring Python code. If I make my symbols unique enough (i.e. `specific_term` instead of `value`), and avoid dynamic attribute access as much as possible, at least I can count on `grep` to get me 99% of the way.

Comment: Your pattern does not fit my case. My farm is (in the general case) a group of three animals, horse, pig and duck, two persons, a truck and other stuff, and it gets passed those parameters on initialization. I prefer not to derive from many classes (pylint will complain if you derive from more than 6 classes I think), so what I do is to define the members of my Farm as  attributes.

Comment: I agree with your comment on grep, and I also use it extensively.